TypeError: ForeignKey(None) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
I recently developed a web app and tested its deployment on Nginx and it worked just fine. The client has a preference for Apache though and I created a config file. After this, I am getting a 500 server error and the error above is presenting itself.
Below is part of the traceback in the Apache error log:
[Tue Aug 06 19:48:10.945075 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 344644] [remote 169.255.52.63:23675]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
[Tue Aug 06 19:48:10.945077 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 344644] [remote 169.255.52.63:23675]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
[Tue Aug 06 19:48:10.945079 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 344644] [remote 169.255.52.63:23675]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Tue Aug 06 19:48:10.945082 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 344644] [remote 169.255.52.63:23675]   File "/var/www/mysite/vir/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/models.py", line 48, in <module>
[Tue Aug 06 19:48:10.945086 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 344644] [remote 169.255.52.63:23675]     class LogEntry(models.Model):
[Tue Aug 06 19:48:10.945089 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 344644] [remote 169.255.52.63:23675]   File "/var/www/mysite/vir/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/models.py", line 54, in LogEntry
[Tue Aug 06 19:48:10.945090 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 344644] [remote 169.255.52.63:23675]     user = models.ForeignKey(
[Tue Aug 06 19:48:10.945092 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 344644] [remote 169.255.52.63:23675]   File "/var/www/mysite/vir/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 959, in __init__
[Tue Aug 06 19:48:10.945094 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 344644] [remote 169.255.52.63:23675]     raise TypeError(
[Tue Aug 06 19:48:10.945099 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 344644] [remote 169.255.52.63:23675] TypeError: ForeignKey(None) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'

I opened django/db/models/fields/related.py and found the source of the exception:
def __init__(
        self,
        to,
        on_delete,
        related_name=None,
        related_query_name=None,
        limit_choices_to=None,
        parent_link=False,
        to_field=None,
        db_constraint=True,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        try:
            to._meta.model_name
        except AttributeError:
            if not isinstance(to, str):
                raise TypeError(
                    "%s(%r) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be "
                    "either a model, a model name, or the string %r"
                    % (
                        self.__class__.__name__,
                        to,
                        RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT,
                    )
                )

I know this definitely has to do with failure to establish a connection to the Postgres db but what is exactly causing this?

I have tried changing the db host to that of the server. I get a socket error
I have also changed the psql socket group ownership to www-data but the 500 server error persists.

Running ./manage.py dbshell is working just fine.
Here is my Apache config file:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@adminsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
        ServerName mysite.com
    Alias /static /var/www/mysite/portal/static

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/portal/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /media /home/admin/media
    <Directory /home/admin/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/portal/portal>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess portal python-path=/var/www/mysite/portal python-home=/var/www/mysite/vir
    WSGIProcessGroup portal
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/portal/portal/wsgi.py
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

and this is the wsgi.py file:
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'portal.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
EDIT
I've edited to add part of my settings.py file:
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portal.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': ''
   }
}

# User authentication

AUTH_USER_MODEL = os.getenv("AUTH_USER_MODEL")
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['login.backends.EmailBackend',]


where DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1 and the server is on 41.XX.XX.XX, AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login.CustomUser'
and directory tree:
.
├── portal
│   ├── login
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── portal
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   └── web
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── vir
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    ├── lib64 -> lib
    └── pyvenv.cfg


where is models.py and views.py

Your AUTH_USER_MODEL setting [Django-doc] is somehow set to None, like:
# settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = None
Probably not explicitly though. You might have used for example an environment variable that was not set, or something else.
Look what is setting the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting, and how that returned None.

I've included my AUTH_USER_MODEL config above and I hadn't changed anythng in the settings file prior to the deployment

@t18nao: well likely you did not set the environment variable, so then it uses None. So your environment variables, as said in the answer, is apparently not set. How did you set it?

I used load_env() to load my .env file and I can actually run it just fine in debug with runserver but I can not seem to connect the database to mod_wsgi

@t18nao: but where did you set the environment variables in your container (?)?

in the same directory as manage.py

@t18nao: but just writing an environment variable in the same directory does not include these in the environment.

@t18nao you say that you are using load_env() to load your environment file, assuming whatever package that comes from opens a .env file in the current working directory that can tend to fail considering the actual working directory when your code is run. Considering you're using Apache with the WSGIDaemonProcess directive one solution would be to pass the home option to it.

I'd suggest though to use the __file__ variable and create the absolute file path to your .env file and use that with whatever package you're using to read the correct env file. Also configuring AUTH_USER_MODEL through an environment variable sounds a bit too much, you might want to just configure a different setting file if you want to deploy that project multiple times with different user models, etc.

I managed to solve it. Load_env() was indeed not rendering the environment variables: secret key, database name, host etc.
Here are the things I did:

The .env file was located in the same folder as manage.py. I moved it to the parent folder, in the same folder as venv.
I "downgraded" the running process from launching as root to user.
I ran sudo chown user:user to match the current user.
I added home variable to Apache config file for the DaemonProcess as suggested by Abdul

Now the website is fully online and the database operational.
Thanks for everyone's help.
